# How to make webpack not rename specific files

Tags: webpack, webpack-5

I am trying to figure out webpack for a project and one of the things we would like to do is to replace a few image files during deployment to customize. Replacing the file is easy enough but WebPack renames all of our image files and I fear this will just make things complicated later.

I have an image name "splash.png" and would like webpack to not rename this file, but can rename all the others.

```
 {
    test: /\.(png|svg|jpg|gif)$/,
    type: "asset/resource",
    exclude: [
      path.resolve(__dirname, "../src/assets/images/splash.png")
    ]
  },
```

I have tried the above but it always results in

```
ERROR in ./src/assets/images/splash.png 1:0
Module parse failed: Unexpected character '�' (1:0)

File was processed with these loaders:

* ../../.yarn/cache/image-webpack-loader-npm-7.0.1-3ad4151978-25d704ac0c.zip/node_modules/image-webpack-loader/index.js
You may need an additional loader to handle the result of these loaders.
(Source code omitted for this binary file)
```

Is there a better way to accomplish my end goal? Im willing to move the 'replaceable' files in a separate folder even it it helps.

Answer (score 0):

When using `exclude`, webpack doesn't process the `splash.png` file with the `asset module`, so you get an error for that "excluded" file.

Use the correct rule:

```js
{
  test: /\.(png|svg|jpg|gif)$/,
  type: "asset/resource",
  generator: {
    // keep original filenames and copy images to `dist/img/`
    filename: 'img/[name][ext]', 
  },
},
```